# Listener para mascara monetária e chamar metodo

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma classe para aplicar a mascara monetária, aplico esta classe no listener do editText.

Sendo este um campo para desconto eu preciso que ele faça duas coisas
1 - mostre o valor formatado em nossa moeda ex R$ 21,36 (isto esta Ok)
2 - preciso chamar um método para calcular o total que nada mais é do que o valor (unitario * quantidade) - desconto

é possível ter mais de um listener?

```
 edtDesconto.addTextChangedListener(new MaskMonetaria(edtDesconto));
```

Vamos utilizar a classe MaskMonetaria que esta fazendo o seu papel corretamente, e vamos utilizar a perca do Foco ou seja qdo o usuário sair do campo desconto o calculo do total será chamado desta forma temos o que queremos e funciona! sim, tudo funciona mais tem um porém, que é do motivo de minha pergunta

como esta hoje

```
  edtDesconto.addTextChangedListener(
            new MaskMonetaria(edtDesconto)
            );

    edtTotal.addTextChangedListener(
            new MaskMonetaria(edtTotal)
            );

    edtDesconto.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            EditText et = (EditText)v;

            if (hasFocus){
                // Fazer Nada
                Log.i(TAG, "onFocusChange" + "Tem Foco");
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "onFocusChange" + "Sem Foco");
                calculaTotais();
            }
        }
    });
```

agora os campos na tela

```
- Produto
- valor unitário(desabilitado)
- quantidade
- desconto
- total(desabilitado) 

- Botão Gravar
```

Percebemos aqui que não existe a mudança de foco entre Desconto e o botão Gravar pois entre eles Total esta desabilitado, a ação de gravar os dados finaliza a atividade de forma que o usuário nem vê o Valor Total

Como não consigo no ouvinte ter a classe de formatação e o método que calcula os totais ao mesmo tempo vim a procura de alguma resposta pois acredito que o meu intento deve ser bem comum.

Comment: A ideia de um método chamado `addListener` é indicar ao programador que o listener passado será colocado em paralelo aos demais; isso difere de um método chamado `setListener`, que passa a ideia de que só pode haver um. Agora, claro, para ter certeza é necessário ler a documentação. No caso da API do Android, o `addListener` tem o comportamento esperado. Não sei se é paranoia minha, mas eu poria essas funcionalidades todas na chamada do mesmo listener, que delegaria aos tratadores (aplicador de máscara/calculador de preço) suas necessidades

Comment: Olá Jefferson boa tarde, melhorei a minha pergunta dando mais detalhes, mais gostaria de saber se sua sugestão eu entendi de forma correta, sua sugestão seria eu transformar a classe que dá a mascara monetária como uma classe ou método interno ao ouvinte do campo ex edtDesconto.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()  e neste fazer a mascara e chamar o método de somar?